# django-form-designer with django-cms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-cms

I was able to install [django-form-designer](https://github.com/samluescher/django-form-designer) an include an form into an Django CMS page.

I do not redirect the form, its submitted to the same page.

I get the result mailed, but no success_message is show on the page, just the empty form again. Does this not work out of the box?

Form is here:

http://www.hierundjetzt.ch/de/service/newsletter-verlagsprospekt-facebook/

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the cms_plugin.py file for django-form-designer at the `FormDesignerPlugin`

In the render method is the comment:
`# Redirection does not work with CMS plugin, hence disable:`

and then `process_form` is called with `disable_redirection=True`

Doesn't look like you can do it by default, might be interesting fix to django-cms if the render method returns an HttpResponse to serve that. I'm going to look into that and I might put together a fix to allow that